# How should I deal with multiple data objects that connect together in a UI Automation Framework

Tags: selenium, automation

I'm creating an automation framework.  The test cases are separated from the pages that they interact with.  I'm also dealing with multiple different data objects.  As the framework has gotten more complex, we realized that we have to determine the best way to read this data, add to it, change it, reset it, etc...

Example:
You can have multiple User objects.
A User object can have multiple Group objects, single Email field.
A Group object can have a single Name field, multiple Invited User objects, Member User objects.    
-An Invited User and Member User are *User* objects, but can not have their own groups-

So, if a User creates a Group, invites multiple Users, and some of those Invited Users convert to Member Users... would we:

A) Have the test case pass in a User, Group, and Invited User objects to a page class that creates it.  Then the page class adds the Invited User object to the Group object, and the Group object to the User object.  Then the test case only needs to pass around the User object when it wants to convert some of those Invited Users to Member Users and eventually do cleanup after the test is done.

B) Have the test case pass in a User, Group, and Invited User object to a page class that creates it.  Then the test case would pass in a Group object and Invited User object to a page class to convert them into Member Users.  Then the test case would need to keep those relationships straight when moving through the test and doing cleanup.

C) Have the test case create the objects, but only pass specific fields needed for the operation of the method it is calling.  Create Group would need Name.  Invite User would need Email, etc...  The test case would then need to update the objects and keep the relationship between them (as either a single object, or multiple objects).

Last thing... If C is the best option, at what point do you stop passing in specific fields of the object and just provide the object as a whole?

Comment: I think in your case you should have re-usable procedures instead of page objects.  (or maybe a bit of both... but just use page objects for non-dynamic elements)

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Each test can be decomposed into a number of steps. Some steps automate the web browser. Others insert data to the database, or query the database in order to make assertions. The challenge is to organize these "steps" as methods in one or more classes. An individual test should just call these methods.

The internals for these methods can use selenium page objects, repositories, entity objects — whatever is necessary to perform the test. A sample test could look something like this (you didn't specify a programming language, so I used C#):

```cs
Given.User.Create("Johnny", "Testerson"); // insert user into database
Given.User.LogIn("Johnny", "Testerson"); // use page object to log in

// Use page objects to create group
When.Group.Create(name: "Test group",
                  invites: new [] { "a@example.com", "b@example.com" });

// Query database, make assertions
Then.Group.InvitesShouldBeSent(group: "Test group",
                               recipients: new [] { "a@example.com", "b@example.com" });
```